# Как разрешить С++11 в Android Studio

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, c++11, android-ndk

Всем привет,
Я использую Android studio 1.3.2 и пытаюсь построить проект с использованием нативного кода и C++11 features (share_ptr, weak_ptr and etc.), но получаю ошибки. К примеру:

> Error:(22, 6) error: 'shared_ptr' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type

Задавал вопрос [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667374/how-to-enable-c11-for-android-studio), но пока без ответа.

Суть проблемы: Как использовать С++11 и Android Studio+NDK?

p.s.
Пробовал добавлять флаг `cppFlags.add ("-std=c++11")` в файл проекта "build.gradle"

```
android.ndk {
    moduleName = "game"
    cppFlags.addAll(["-I${file("src/main/jni/native_app_glue")}".toString(),
                     "-I${file("src/main/jni")}".toString(),
                     "-I${file("src/main/jni/data")}".toString()])
    cppFlags.add ("-std=c++11")
    ldLibs.addAll(["android", "EGL", "GLESv2", "OpenSLES", "log"])
    stl        = "stlport_static"
}
```

но похоже это не работает.

Comment: А вы какой версией ndk пользуетесь?

Comment: Использую android-ndk-r11b-windows-x86_64.

Comment: Совсем глупый вопрос, а вы подключали  <memory> там где используете shared_ptr?

Comment: В прошлых версиях, с которыми приходилось работать, поддержка c++ была не ахти (к тому же мне нужен был boost и c++14), в итоге использовал https://www.crystax.net/

Comment: Unick, да я подключил <memory>

Comment: Vladimir Gamalian, спасибо, crystax.net, возможно, пригодится :)

Answer (score 3):

Ответ на свой вопрос получил [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667374/how-to-enable-c11-for-android-studio). Michael порекомендовал использовать libc++ или gnustl. Я использовал gnustl.